# Search column for specific phrases and count the amount of times they appear in the column and plot to bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, seaborn

Search column for each month of the year. Column is organized like this "01-Jan-2018". I want to find how many times "Jan-2018" appears in the column. Basically count it and plot it on a bar graph. I want it to show all the quantities for "Jan-2018" , "Feb-2018", etc. Should be 12 bars on the graph. Maybe using count or sum. I am pulling the data from a CSV using pandas and python.

I have tried to printing it out onto the console with some success. But I am getting confused as correct way to search a portion of the date.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    import csv 
    import seaborn as sns

    data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rmond\Downloads\PS_csvFile1.csv', error_bad_lines=False, encoding="ISO-8859-1", skiprows=6)
    cols = data.columns 
    cols = cols.map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_') if isinstance(x, (str)) else x)
    data.columns = cols
    print(data.groupby('Case_Date').mean().plot(kind='bar'))
```

I am expecting the a bar graph that will show the total quantity for each month. So there should be 12 bar graphs. But I am not sure how to search the column 12 times and each time only looking for the data of each month. While excluding the date, only searching for the month and year.

Comment: print(pd.value_counts(data['Case_Date'].str.contains('Mar-2018')))

                          Use this in place of what is posted there. I figured out how to call 1 month. I need to figure out how to check the count for all 12 months now

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this is what you need.

Let's work with the below dataframe as input dataframe.

```
    date
0   1/31/2018
1   2/28/2018
2   2/28/2018
3   3/31/2018
4   4/30/2018
5   5/31/2018
6   6/30/2018
7   6/30/2018
8   7/31/2018
9   8/31/2018
10  9/30/2018
11  9/30/2018
12  9/30/2018
13  9/30/2018
14  10/31/2018
15  11/30/2018
16  12/31/2018
```

The below mentioned lines of code will get the number of count for each month as a bar graph. When you have a column as as datetime object, a lot of function are much easy & the contents of the column are much more flexible. With that, you don't need search string of the name of the month.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['my']=df.date.dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
ax = df.groupby('my', sort=False)['my'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_xticklabels(df.my, rotation=90);
```

**Output**

[image]